# how to delete document from mongoose after certain time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

so I need to automatically delete document from collection after 2 minutes if paramter `isValidated`is set to false, now I made this:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const Model = mongoose.model;

const UserSchema = new Schema(
  {
    email: {
      type: String,
    },
    username: { type: String },
    createdAt: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now,
    },
    points: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    validation: {
      type: String,
    },
    isValidated: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    roles: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Role",
      },
    ],
    password: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
  { collection: "users" }
);

UserSchema.index(
  { createdAt: 1 },
  {
    expireAfterSeconds: 120,
    partialFilterExpression: { isValidated: false },
  }
);

const User = Model("User", UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

But this `.index` is not working, and I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this to work you have to create the indexing on the field `createdAt` first and  then you have to create TTL indexes so that MongoDB can use to automatically remove documents from a collection after a certain amount of time.

```
db.collectionName.createIndex( { "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 120 } )
```

You should check [here](https://dev.to/lironer/delete-expired-documents-automatically-with-mongodb-ttl-index-l44) for more details.

Or, Just try adding this to the schema, but this will just delete the documents in 2 minutes(This will help you understand if there is an issue with Conditional delete or not, follow the above link):

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const Model = mongoose.model;

const UserSchema = new Schema(
  {
    email: {
      type: String,
    },
    username: { type: String },
    createdAt: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now,
      expires: 120
    },
    points: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    validation: {
      type: String,
    },
    isValidated: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    roles: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Role",
      },
    ],
    password: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
  { collection: "users" }
);

const User = Model("User", UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I actually created expires_at field and it created index in mongodb atlas, but when I deleted that expires_at the index wasn't deleted. So that was causing problem