Auto delete unverified user after certain hours
I have a condition where if user email not unverified after 8 hours, their data will be automatically deleted, starting from after signing in.
The question is, How to make a trigger from that condition in AuthJs (NextAuth)?
P.S.: I'm using Mongoose, MongoDb, AuthJs (NextAuth), and NextJs
My AuthJs (NextAuth) config:
export const { auth, handlers, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth({
    adapter: MongoDBAdapter(client),
    session: { strategy: "jwt" },
    callbacks: {
        async session({ session, token, user }) {
            // `session.user.address` is now a valid property, and will be type-checked
            // in places like `useSession().data.user` or `auth().user`
            return {
                ...session,
                user: {
                    ...session.user,
                },
            }
        },

    },

    ...authConfig,
})

My User Schema:
import { Schema, Model, Types, Document, model, models } from 'mongoose';

export interface Users extends Document {
    name: string
    email: string
}

const UserSchema = new Schema<Users>({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
})

export default models.User || model<Users>('User', UserSchema)


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67182332/how-to-delete-document-from-mongoose-after-certain-time


Add a Timestamp Field: Include a field in your user schema to track
when the user was created.
Scheduled Cleanup Job: Use a background job to periodically check
for and delete unverified users.
Verification Status: Add a field to your schema to indicate whether
the email is verified.



const UserSchema = new Schema<Users>({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    isVerified: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    },
}, { timestamps: true }); // This will automatically add `createdAt` and `updatedAt` fields.

export default models.User || model<Users>('User', UserSchema);




Schedule a Cleanup Job



    cron.schedule('0 * * * *', async () => { // Run every hour
        const eightHoursAgo = new Date(Date.now() - 8 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    
        try {
            await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
                useNewUrlParser: true,
                useUnifiedTopology: true,
            });
    
            const result = await User.deleteMany({
                isVerified: false,
                createdAt: { $lt: eightHoursAgo },
            });
    
            console.log(`Deleted ${result.deletedCount} unverified users.`);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Error cleaning up unverified users:', err);
        } finally {
            await mongoose.connection.close();
        }
    });




Verification Workflow
Ensure your email verification process updates the isVerified field in the database once the user verifies their email.

If you want to initiate cleanup within your authentication logic (e.g., after each sign-in), you can add the following in your NextAuth callbacks:
callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user }) {
        const eightHoursAgo = new Date(Date.now() - 8 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

        if (!user.isVerified && user.createdAt < eightHoursAgo) {
            // Delete user if unverified for more than 8 hours
            await User.deleteOne({ _id: user._id });
            throw new Error("User registration expired. Please register again.");
        }

        return true;
    },
    // Other callbacks...
},


how to avoid error on !user.isVerified and user.createdAt?

@FebryAryo - why would there be an error?

the error said "Property 'isVerified' does not exist on type 'User | AdapterUser'."

Add the isverified field to your Users  interface
''
export interface Users extends Document {
name: string
email: string
isVerified : boolean
}
